# How gnu linker choose which dynamic library to link

Tags: c++, cuda, g++, ld

I was using gpgpu-sim, a GPU simulator, to conduct researches. There are several `.so` files in my own folder: 
[image: My own folder]

And there are some alternatives `.so` in Nvidia's cudart lib folder:
[image: Nvidia's folder]

And there are some `.o` files and need to be linked with libcudart.so, when I type in the command:

```
g++ -L "Path/to/MyFolder" -l cudart *.o
```

I hope the generated a.out would link to libcudart.so, but it just linked to a strange so file:

```
    libcudart_gpgpu-sim_git-commit-6443f21d433f1b642003867e56fe1f54efae55e3_modified_0.so => not found
```

And when I typed this code:

```
g++ -L "Path/to/NvidiaFolder" -l cudart *.o
```

The program can sussessfully find libcudart.so.9 in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH folder,but it shows that the version can't match!:

```
./a.out: /path/to/myFolder/libcudart.so.9.0: version `libcudart.so.9.0'not found (required by ./a.out)
```

Can anybody tell me how `ld` works and how to solve those problems?

Comment: Why `-lcuda` if the goal is to link  libcudart? Would you not need to specify `-lcudart` in that case?

Comment: sorry, I write the wrong question, I did use -lcudart

Comment: you reported that when linking with NvidiaFolder the program successfully find libcuda.so.9. Does that mean hte linker succesfully produce an executable?

Comment: Does the report error `libcudart.so.9.0'not found comes from runtime, that is during execution of your program? If this is the case, are you sure you set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH prepending the correct path before any other search path?

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out the reason.
if you use this code to link objects to generate a shared library:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libNAME_A.so -o libNAME_B.so
```

then, if some on is trying to link NAME_B.so using:

```
g++ <INPUT> -lNAME_B -o <OUTPUT>
```

the output will finally look for libNAME_A.so.

refer to g++ man page:

> ```
>    -Wl,option
>        Pass option as an option to the linker.  If option contains commas,
>        it is split into multiple options at the commas.  You can use this
>        syntax to pass an argument to the option.  For example,
>        -Wl,-Map,output.map passes -Map output.map to the linker.  When
>        using the GNU linker, you can also get the same effect with
>        -Wl,-Map=output.map.
> ```

and for ld man page:

> ```
> -soname=name
>        When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME
>        field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a
>        shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable
>        is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object
>        specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file
>        name given to the linker.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing to do with CUDA here, it's just a linking and runtime environment setup problem.

The ld linker searches for objects and library archives following the order specified by -L option parameters, and only after into default system directories. The linker will link the object code that first match this search.

At runtime, if you linked against dynamic libraries (.so files) you will need to properly define the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable with a list of paths to look for dynamic libraries, separated by colon (:).

So if you link to your objects using libraries from your local path (assuming you are looking for libcudart.so):

```
g++  -o myprogram *.o -L "/Path/to/myFolder" -lcudart
```

you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as follows before running your program:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Path/to/myFolder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
./myprogram
```

I hope this help and clarify your understanding. Frankly I don't understand the origin of your libcudart_gpgpu-sim_git-commit match

Comment: I did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /Path/to/myFolder, but a.out shows libcudart_gpgpu-sim_git-commit-8ec70c69eb89c1fa836c233be3e4c478602d9bb7_modified_2.so => not found, there is no such a file at all

Comment: @JiangqiuShen Try linking to the nvidia CUDA SDK library (not the ones coming with gpgpu-sim) and **prepend** CUDA_SDK library path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable as follows:`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/nvidia/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: The error is a compilation/linking error, not a runtime error. LD_LIBRARY_PATH  is irrelevant

Comment: @Luca Ferraro  but  I really need to use libcudart.so in my folder

Comment: @talonmies I addressed the question on "how ld works" and linking to dynamic library requires setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime, so I mentioned both for completeness and clarification for the user. I think we cannot solve the problem Shen addressed, but we can clarify which library should link and how to do that. I'm not satisfied with the downvote.